# Stripe authorisation only transaction

Tags: javascript, php, transactions, stripe-payments

I want to use an authorisation only transaction to check if a user has sufficient funds in their card before making a payment. If they do it will create a real transaction; if not it will return an error displaying "insufficient funds".

Is there a way to do this? I've surfed the web and I haven't found anything useful. Also, will this mean that my user has to go through 2 payment processes on my website to do the two transactions? Or can I make everything automatic so that the user only sees one transaction?

Thanks for the help! :)

The code will look something like this:

```
if (authorisation transaction succeeds) {
    // Create a legitimate automatic transaction
} else {
    echo "Please add sufficient funds to your card";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Create Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) API is synchronous which means that you either get an [error](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors) back which indicates the payment failed or a [Charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object) back which indicates that the payment succeeded.

Running an authorization first would just require you to pass `capture: false` as a parameter indicating that you want to hold the funds on the card and capture those later (up to 7 days). You would get the exact same behavior as creating the charge directly and the bank could decline the charge because of insufficient funds but also for a variety of other reasons without giving you any details. In the end that would be the same as just trying to create the charge and catch errors.

If you still want to use this [flow](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture) then once you get the charge object back you would just have to use the [Capture Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#capture_charge) API to effectively capture the charge.